# Reducing an array to return grouped data from schools to local authorities

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grouping

I have a bit of JS code that I use to draw svg circles on the page. The circles are a based on school data and the size of the circle is dependant on the SchoolCapacity field. The problem is that my array **schooldata** contains 100s of elements and the circles are very crowded and overlap over each other. My question is how can I rewrite the **process schools data** code to display Local Authorities (**LA (Name)**) and their school capacities as draw those as circles instead.

***Array of school data:***

```
const schooldata = [{
    "URN": 135691,
    "LA (code)": 938,
    "LA (name)": "West Sussex",
    "EstablishmentNumber": 6228,
    "EstablishmentName": "Seadown School",
    "SchoolCapacity": 30,
    "Postcode": "BN11 2BE"
  }, {
    "URN": 112080,
    "LA (code)": 908,
    "LA (name)": "Cornwall",
    "EstablishmentNumber": 6084,
    "EstablishmentName": "St Ia School",
    "SchoolCapacity": 45,
    "Postcode": "TR26 2SF"
  },
    {
    "URN": 130842,
    "LA (code)": 938,
    "LA (name)": "West Sussex",
    "EstablishmentNumber": 8003,
    "EstablishmentName": "Greater Brighton Metropolitan College",
    "SchoolCapacity": "",
    "Postcode": "BN12 6NU"
  },
```

***JS Business logic***

```
  function getcoordinates(postcode) {
    let url = "https://api.getthedata.com/postcode/" + postcode.replace(" ", "+");
    try {
      return fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); // Process it inside the `then`
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  //svg setup
  var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    container = document.getElementById('cont');
  
  function drawcircle(easting, northing, size, label, identifier) {
    var xScale = (container.width.baseVal.value - 20) / (700000);
    var x = 10 + (xScale * easting);
    var yScale = (container.height.baseVal.value - 20) / (700000);
    var y = 10 + (yScale * (700000 - northing));
    var sizeScale = 100;
    var radius = size / sizeScale;
  
    //draw or update the svg circle
    var circle = document.getElementById("Circle_" + identifier);
    if (circle == null) {
      circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    }
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "Circle_" + identifier);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', radius);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: #c6605e; stroke: none; stroke-width: 1px;');
    container.appendChild(circle);
  
    //draw or update the circle label
    var newText = document.getElementById("Circle_Label_" + identifier);
    if (newText == null) {
      newText = document.createElementNS(svgns, "text");
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(label);
      newText.appendChild(textNode);
    }
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "Circle_Label_" + identifier);
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
    newText.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", "10");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(label);
    newText.replaceChild(textNode, newText.childNodes[0]);
    container.appendChild(newText);
  }
  
  **//process schools data** -- TODO: change to LA instead of schools
  let schools = schooldata.reduce(function(allSchools, school) {
    allSchools[school.EstablishmentName] = {
      SchoolCapacity: school.SchoolCapacity || 0,
      coordinates: []
    };
    getcoordinates(school.Postcode).then(function(data) {
      allSchools[school.EstablishmentName].coordinates.push([data.data.easting, data.data.northing]);
      drawcircle(data.data.easting, data.data.northing, school.SchoolCapacity, school.EstablishmentName, school.URN);
    });
    return allSchools
  }, {});
```

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
          
<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="cont" width="900" height="900"></svg>
```

I assume I need to do some Array reducing?

Comment: Did you try changing school.EstablishmentName to school['LA (name)'] in your current reduce?

Comment: @James I did indeed, but the LA name is displayed however it is duplicated, I want to draw just one circle. for each LA so that it is more readable.

Comment: For each LA do you want all school capacities summed up?

Comment: Yes. I do. I have edited my previous comment with an update.

Comment: Some schools have "" as their capacity

Comment: Assumed to be 0 as data has not been provided at https://get-information-schools.service.gov.uk/

Comment: What data for each LA do you want to retain?  "LA (code)", "LA (name)", say "SchoolsCapacity" ?

Comment: LA (Code), LA (Name), SchoolCapacity (sum of all in each LA (Name) group) and the postcode of the first item in each grouped LA.

The postcode is what determines the location of where the circle will be drawn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243152/discussion-between-re-za-and-riku-das).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reduce your schools to Local Authorities using `Array.reduce()`:

```
const locAuthorities = schooldata.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
  const laCode = curr["LA (code)"]
  const laName = curr["LA (name)"]
  if (prev[laCode]) {
    prev[laCode].SchoolCapacity += curr.SchoolCapacity || 0
  } else {
    prev[laCode] = {
      "LA (code)": laCode,
      "LA (name)": laName,
      "SchoolCapacity": curr.SchoolCapacity,
      "Postcode": curr.Postcode,
      "URN": curr.URN
    }
  }
  return prev
}, {})

const locAuthoritiesArray = Object.values(locAuthorities)
```

Now use `localAuthoritiesArray` to draw the circles:

```
locAuthoritiesArray.forEach(function (la) {
  getcoordinates(la.Postcode).then(function (data) {
    drawcircle(
      data.data.easting,
      data.data.northing,
      la.SchoolCapacity,
      la["LA (name)"],
      la.URN
    );
  });
})
```